# How do I get a certain object key via a function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create error messages for form validation in multiple languages.
Unfortunately, the transfer of the "target" parameter to my function does not work. Maybe target is interpreted as a string?!

```
function formMessages(field, target) {
  var messages = {
    'de' : {
      'valueMissing': 'Bitte füllen Sie dieses Feld aus.',
      'typeMismatch': {
        'email': 'Bitte geben Sie eine E-Mail ein.',
        'url': 'Bitte geben Sie eine URL ein.'
      }
    }
  };

  // Don't work!
  // return messages.de.target;

  // This works! But it is not dynamic!
  // return messages.de.typeMismatch.email;
}

if (validity.typeMismatch) {
  // Email
  if (field.type === 'email') return formMessages(field, 'typeMismatch.email');
}
```

Comment: Try to `console.log(messages["de"]["valueMissing"]);` in order to see if you actually go to the message.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key

Comment: That's because you are passing string as argument and are using dot notation, instead use [ ] notation and pass 'typeMismatch' , 'email' as two separate arguments or spilt() 'typeMismatch.email' into two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use <kbd>[eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)</kbd> Method

```
return eval('messages.de.'+target);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
function formMessages(field, target) {
  var messages = {
    de: {
      valueMissing: "Bitte füllen Sie dieses Feld aus.",
      typeMismatch: {
        email: "Bitte geben Sie eine E-Mail ein.",
        url: "Bitte geben Sie eine URL ein."
      }
    }
  };

  return target.split(".").reduce((re, v) => re[v], messages.de);

  // This works! But it is not dynamic!
  // return messages.de.typeMismatch.email;
}

if (validity.typeMismatch) {
  // Email
  if (field.type === "email") return formMessages(field, "typeMismatch.email");
}
```

`messages.de.target`equals`messages['de']['target']`,so `target` works as string.

If you want `target` works as variable,it should be `messages.de[target]`.

However,in your case,`target` is `typeMismatch.email`,so you have to use `reduce` to accumulate.

Answer (score 0):

Use bracket notation to access the dynamic property

```
function formMessages(field) 
{
  var messages = {
    'de' : {
      'valueMissing': 'Bitte füllen Sie dieses Feld aus.',
      'typeMismatch': {
        'email': 'Bitte geben Sie eine E-Mail ein.',
        'url': 'Bitte geben Sie eine URL ein.'
      }
    }
  };

  return messages.de.typeMismatch[ field.type ]; //pass the field.type itself
}

if (validity.typeMismatch) 
{
  if ( field.type === 'email') return formMessages(field); //pass the field itself
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing strings as arguments then use [ ] notation and pass 'typeMismatch' , 'email' as two separate arguments.

```
function formMessages(field, target1, target2) {
  var messages = {
    'de' : {
      'valueMissing': 'Bitte füllen Sie dieses Feld aus.',
      'typeMismatch': {
        'email': 'Bitte geben Sie eine E-Mail ein.',
        'url': 'Bitte geben Sie eine URL ein.'
      }
    }
  };

  return messages.de[target1][target2];

}

if (validity.typeMismatch) {
  // Email
  if (field.type === 'email') return formMessages(field, 'typeMismatch', 'email');
}
```